# Reading JSON Link from Wordpress into a Table

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress

I have a problem to construct my data into a table since currently each row i have is creating a new table. I am using the JSON Content Importer and below is the code i have:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work?

```
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Shoes</th>
   <th>Premier League</th>
   <th>Serie A</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
[jsoncontentimporter url= basenode=data]
 <tr>
     <td>{id}</td>
     <td>{shoes}</td>
     <td>{premierleague}</td>
     <td>{seriea}</td>
 </tr>
[/jsoncontentimporter]
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes it good thanks mate